# How to implement GMSMarker drag drop on GMSMapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, drag-and-drop, google-maps-sdk-ios

1. I set the marker on google map but when i drag it's all of map are drag.
2. I want drag marker when click and drag on it's
3. and drag map when click and drag outside marker.

this is my code

```c
self.camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86 longitude:151.20 zoom:6 bearing:0 viewingAngle:0];
self.Map = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.MapView.bounds camera:self.camera];
self.Map.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.Map.delegate = self;

GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = self.camera.target;
marker.draggable = YES;
marker.title = @"Sydney";
marker.snippet = @"Australia";
marker.map = self.Map;
marker.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;

[self.MapView addSubview:self.Map];
```

and this is event on drag drop

```c
- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didBeginDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{

}

- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didEndDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{

}

- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didDragMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{

}
```

when i run my app and debug all above event not work.
but event click on marker work well.

how i implement drag drop ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to press-and-hold on the marker before it will begin dragging. I thought it wasn't working either until someone pointed this out... really needs to be in Google's documentation.

Comment: Is there a possibility to drag like tap & drag