# Is it possible to change a route by dragging its polyline in a GMSMapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm currently working on an app using the latest version of the Google Maps SDK for iOS and I've been wondering if it's possible to achieve the same "drag and drop" feature available in the web version of Google Maps to get a custom route.

After completely reading the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/) I still haven't found an answer or guidance related to this feature, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the drag and drop feature can be done by creating an instance of `GMDraggableMarkerManager` and sets itself as the delegate in order to be notified of drag events.

Steps given in [google-maps-sdk-ios-drag-drop](https://github.com/rweindl/google-maps-sdk-ios-drag-drop) are as follows:

> 1. To initialize the drag & drop functionality you have to import
>      the `GMDraggableMarkerManager.h` in your UIViewController displaying
>      the map.
> 2. Create a property for the `GMDraggableMarkerManager`.
> 3. After the initialization of the Google Maps View you have to
>      initialize the `draggableMarkerManager`.

Please note that to fully implement drag and drop feature, a long press on the marker enables you to drag it around and set it to another position

This SO post - 
[How to implement GMSMarker drag drop on GMSMapView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294545/how-to-implement-gmsmarker-drag-drop-on-gmsmapview) might also help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Teyam , but I want to apply the effect over the route drawed in the map (GMSPolyline) and you are referring to a marker

Comment: Did you find a way to change the route by dragging?